# SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST but missing "where" clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a customer who claims they're doing `select` with `where` clauses, but with `show full processlist` those `where` clauses do not show up. Could such a behaviour be caused by very sparse logging settings, or is it most likely they have some sub query that indeed selects the whole table?

Comment: It seems more a claim than an actual issue to me, I have never faced such issue. You can debug this *claim* with [The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html#:~:text=To%20disable%20or%20enable%20the,name%20of%20the%20log%20file.)

Comment: Thank you that seems very helpful.